# pyrocms 2.2 upgrade database Error Number: 1054

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, pyrocms

Since I upgraded to pyrocms 2.2 I have an error in my search form.

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'project_name` LIKE '%project%'' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM `default_projects` WHERE `project_name`` LIKE '%project%'`
```

Here is my controller

```
 $project_name="'%".$_POST['project_name']."%'";
```

and my model :

```
 $test = "`project_name` LIKE $name ";
 $this->db->where($test);
 return $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

I just paste the simplest query because my function is quite big.
So this was working with pyrocms 2.1 but not anymore.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using:

```
$this->db->like('project_name',$name);
```

[Codeigniter DB active record docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)